# SecureString password stored in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, hash, securestring

I believe I'm misunderstanding a fundamental part of `SecureString`. I understand that `string`'s are immutable and there a password or sensitive data is found as clear text on the heap.

What I'm struggling to understand is, how do I use `SecureString` in a client application which needs to verify the hashed password in a database?

Here's my context:

- I'm using a WPF client application.
- I have a local SQL database (on the client's machine)
- The passwords are hashed and stored in the database.
- The user tries logging into to my WPF application
- The PasswordBox control stores the password in a `SecureString` via the `SecurePassword` property.

Now what? **How do I hash a `SecureString` WITHOUT casting it back into string first?**

All the advise I've received so far is to write extension methods converting `SecureString` to `String`, hash it and then send it to db to verify. **But this defeats the whole exercise!**

Must I just accept that `SecureString` is useless in my mentioned context and use plain `string`?

Comment: Personally, I find very little use for SecureString - they add very little security to an application for all of the effort they take to actually use properly. At the end of the day, a truly dedicated attacker will get your password because it must be stored in memory **somewhere**... the idea that SecureStrings will make it harder is true, but if an attacker is already looking at memory then I assume they're dedicated enough to get past it anyways.

Comment: Let the database deal with the password. Send the username and password to a stored procedure, which will return whether the authentication was successful. You can deal with all of the encryption stuff in the procedure.

Comment: @MikeEason Send password as cleartext to a stored procedure? Never!

Comment: I want to make a warning / addition to this as it is dependend to some details. for example you should a secure connection. otherwise "everyone" could read the password from the network stream. If he is usin secure strings its indicating that he wants to secure his passwords ;) @Niels have a look at my answer

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Well, I'm no expert on this subject, it would be wise to encrypt the password before sending it, however it would then be required that the server, and the application would share the same encryption key(?). I would love to see a grand solution to that problem, if there is one!

Comment: @MikeEason Passwords must not be *encrypted*, since that would suggest they can be decrypted. Rather they must be *hashed* with a one-way function. Then this is stored in the database and the user-submitted value is also hashed and these are compared.

Comment: Sami is right, encryption in this scenario are always risky. Perhaps little better with asymmetric strategies (e.g. RSA)  but thats somelike a whole different approach : )

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392538/securestring-to-byte-c-sharp

Comment: @MikeEason There is no encryption key, just a shared hashing algorithm. More or less, the client takes whatever input the user typed in, perhaps with a salt, performs **some sort of algorithm on it**, (It doesn't really matter what type of algorithm, to be honest - it just needs to be repeatable, non-reversible and preferably with low chance of collisions) then checks to see if the database has the same hash, which is obviously saved into the database when the user account was created.

Answer (score 4):

SecureString is represented as a byte[] you could encode the bytes e.g. with bitconverter and save the result.
Furthermore SecureString is a encryption not a hash as it can be decrypted. (see below)

SecureString mainly meant to store sensitive data **in memory**. 
If you have a service / website, this is not as important as the values which are stored in the database. These should never be plaintext, and imo **not be decryptable** by your or any administrator
Also i'm not sure wether another server could decrypt the strings, so you may have a problem when you change the server or have somekind of cluster scenario.

Especially for passwords would prefer using hash algorithms (e.g. [SHA256](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256(v=vs.110).aspx)) .
These can't be uncrypted (like the sum of the digits). 
In the use case of a login funtionality you would  encrypt the userinput and compare the hashs the user and and the one thats in the database. (details se below)
I would also suggest to add a dynamic criteria like the userid to the hashinput so that 2 user with same password would have different hashes.

With this strategy you don't have a risc with userpasswords and therefore if data gets leaked it wouldn't be a problem at this point.

Here an short overview of using **hash algorithms**

So ( if the securestring is given) first [decrypt the SecureString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818704/how-to-convert-securestring-to-system-string)

```
String SecureStringToString(SecureString value){
  IntPtr valuePtr = IntPtr.Zero;
  try{
    valuePtr = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(value);
    return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(valuePtr);
  }
  finally{
    Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(valuePtr);
  }
}
```

Than hash it for example with SHA256. [From this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999361/sha-256-hash-in-c-sharp)

```
  using (SHA256 hash = SHA256Managed.Create()) {
    Encoding enc = Encoding.UTF8;

    //the user id is the salt. 
    //So 2 users with same password have different hashes. 
    //For example if someone knows his own hash he can't see who has same password
    string input = userInput+userId;
    Byte[] result = hash.ComputeHash(enc.GetBytes(input));

    foreach (Byte b in result)
      Sb.Append(b.ToString("x2")); //You could also use other encodingslike BASE64 
  }
```

Store this hashsum. Depending on your encoding it may looke like this:

> ac5b208b4d35ec79fa7c14b7a31f9c80392cdab2bc58bc5b79bcfe64b044d899

in your database.
If the user signs on then create the hash from his input and compare it with the hash in the database. if they are equal then the password is correct.
Therefore you never need to have the plaintext user password anywhere stored.

If the client makes the hash then it should absolut should no where exist as a plaintext (except the textbox if it doesnt support the securestring)

PS: this is only one option. But the main thing is to **never** store plaintextpasswords anywhere. For best never know them and have no change to get them decrypted.

Another strategy would be to use **asymmetric encryptions** like [RSA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) but this can become more complex. If you need help with that i would recommend a dedicated post on this.

Depending on your requirements and envionment most of the time hashsums should be an acceptable solution. (But thats not an legal advice as i'm not a lawyer)

Comment: Also it is advisable to add some kind of salt into the hashing process (simply append some constant random bytes to the bytes of the password). This will make using rainbow tables and other attacks on hashes more difficult. But this is also worth another whole post and information can be found on the web on this.

Comment: Right ! das mentioned above the user id : )  Also it prevents some attacks if a user may get to know his hash he may look up other users with same hash. without salt he could login with his password.

Comment: Ah, true, didn't notice it there inside the code. Sorry :)

Comment: I made it more clear with an comment in the code :)

Comment: @Boas Enkler, Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm fine with the hashing process etc and agree with you. You however mention I should _decrypting the SecureString and then hash it_, but the decrypt example and link you posted, brings the SecureString back into a string defeating the entire purpose I'm trying to achieve. Then I may as well just have used string. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: The secure String is only needed if You hold Objekts with the password in ram

Comment: If my post solved your question please consider marking it as the solution

Comment: @Boas, But I do hold my password in RAM? I think we have a misunderstanding. When I capture the password from the user, the value gets stored into RAM (hence my need for SecureString). If you can show me a way of creating a hash from the SecureString instance without first going back to String, then I will mark you answer as the solution.

Comment: As described above. First decrypt the secure string ( first example SecureStringToString) then you can hash the password and store it in the database

Comment: I appreciate the help, please re-read my question. "Is there a way for me to Hash the `SecureString`, **WITHOUT first casting it to `string`!**".

Comment: You need to go directly from a `SecureString` to a `byte[]` without the intermediate `string` step first!