# C# & WPF - Using SecureString for a client-side HTTP API password

Tags: c#, wpf, httpclient, securestring

When writing a WPF application, the `PasswordBox` stores the entered password as a `SecureString`. This totally makes sense. However, I want to send the password via a HTTP API, and the `HttpClient` PostAsync seems to accept strings for form-encoded data.

I am aware that other people have asked related questions, most notably [Is SecureString ever practical in a C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26190938/is-securestring-ever-practical-in-a-c-sharp-application), but I have not found a satisfactory method to send this `SecureString` to the Http endpoint, without first converting it to a `String`. The conversion totally defeats the object of `SecureString` in the first place (because it puts the plaintext right back into the managed memory).

Is there a canonically correct (and preferably straightforward) way to do this?

For complete disclosure - I have no control over the HTTP API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that, although not perfect, the best solution for you is to use the `DecryptSecureString` method, posted by [rdev5](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901156/rdev5) on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33679932/5686352) answer (after all, the password is being transfered in plaintext over the network anyway)

rdev5's method decrypts the `SecureString` into a string, do what you tell it to do with the password and then wipe it from memory. This reduces the window where the password is in the memory, and thus the time that it could be peeked from there.

```
Strings.DecryptSecureString(secureString, (password) =>
{
    // Do your API call here
});
```

*P.S.*: As pointed out in the original post, just be sure not to save the content of `password` elsewhere.

Comment: It might not be globally ideal, but it does solve the problem of the lack of a `DisposableString` type. So thankyou. I would like to note that the password is not technically sent in plaintext since the HTTP API is a secure connection.