# How to get a SecureString out of an Azure KeyVault - C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-keyvault

I have a Azure KeyVault providing a password which I'd like to read into a SecureString.

If I try to read the string as a SecureString from the IConfiguration object, it will return a null:

```
config.GetValue<SecureString>("AdminPW") == null
```

I can read the string in as a string and convert to SecureString, but this seems like a dirty hack:

```
 var pass = new SecureString();
 foreach (var c in config.GetValue<string>("AdminPW").ToCharArray())
 {
    pass.AppendChar(c);
 }
```

Is there a way to get a SecureString directly from the IConfiguration?

Comment: It is pointless, the string you got out of config.GetValue() already leaks the secret.  SecureString got pointless a long time ago.  Focus on physical security, a door with a lock and a solid recycling procedure to discard old hardware.

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818704/how-to-convert-securestring-to-system-string You need to use the InteropServices.Marshal class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans said, it is not security.

> If the assemblies you are using don't have native support for `SecureString` serialization, that's exactly where you Key Vault as a service for secrets need to pass them only an encrypted payload which when you do decrypt is kept immediately in a SecureString (CryptoStream byte by byte to SecureString followed by dispose to purge the buffers from memory).

So not suggest you get a SecureString out of an Azure KeyVault.

You could refer to this issue [`Azure KeyVault client should support SecureStrings`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/1819).

Comment: I'm aware that's it's not secure, I'm just using it for a PSCredential object for authentication purposes. I'd just want to get it out of the KeyVault as a secure string to avoid the intermediate steps really.

Comment: You can't get keyvault as secure string.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else checking this, it is not possible to directly get a SecureString out of an Azure KeyVault.